# Cloud Build App Engine Failing INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I'm facing a problem when building my Python 3.7 application hosted on app engine through cloud build. I have 7 steps inside my cloudbuild.yaml file, each step deploys a different version of my application (with configurations of max-min instances different from others). And the error below randomly happens among one of the 7 steps, sometimes it happens on step 3, sometimes on step 7... Everytime I retry the build, this error happens in a different step.

My cloud_build.yaml file:

```
steps:

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud-slim"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "index.yaml", "queue.yaml", "cron.yaml"]
  id: queue-indexes-crons

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud-slim"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "default_prod.yaml", "-v", "master", "--no-cache"]
  id: master-version-default
  waitFor: ["queue-indexes-crons"]

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud-slim"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "api_prod.yaml", "-v", "master", "--no-cache"]
  id: master-version-api
  waitFor: ["queue-indexes-crons"]

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud-slim"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "default_prod_idle.yaml", "-v", "idle", "--no-promote", "--no-cache"]
  id: idle-version-default
  waitFor: ["queue-indexes-crons"]

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud-slim"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "api_prod_idle.yaml", "-v", "idle", "--no-promote", "--no-cache"]
  id: idle-version-api
  waitFor: ["queue-indexes-crons"]

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud-slim"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "default_prod_peak.yaml", "-v", "peak", "--no-promote", "--no-cache"]
  id: peak-version-default
  waitFor: ["queue-indexes-crons"]

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud-slim"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "api_prod_peak.yaml", "-v", "peak", "--no-promote", "--no-cache"]
  id: peak-version-api
  waitFor: ["queue-indexes-crons"]

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud-slim"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "frontend.yaml", "-v", "master", "--no-cache"]
  id: frontend
  waitFor: ["queue-indexes-crons"]

timeout: 2400s
```

Below is a message I got in the build log

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build
> 4663bacb-3842-45b7-97ec-60d2821f74d1 status: FAILURE Build error
> details:
> {"error":{"errorType":"BuildError","canonicalCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorId":"B9BD7715","errorMessage":"20
> Jan 2021 04:04:50 INFO     Arguments:
> ['--parser_script=/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--src=', '--entrypoint=',
> '--name=asia.gcr.io/pyapp45-2020/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:2e34b5db-3bb2-4c20-9f35-86922c702148', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv',
> '--cache-repository=asia.gcr.io/pyapp45-2020/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d',
> '--no-cache', '--builder-output-path=""',
> '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig',
> '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7',
> '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip',
> '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG',
> '--base=asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20201213_3_7_9_RC00']\n20
> Jan 2021 04:04:50 INFO     Unparsed arguments:
> ['--name=asia.gcr.io/pyapp45-2020/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:2e34b5db-3bb2-4c20-9f35-86922c702148', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv',
> '--cache-repository=asia.gcr.io/pyapp45-2020/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d',
> '--no-cache', '--builder-output-path=""',
> '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig',
> '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7',
> '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip',
> '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG',
> '--base=asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20201213_3_7_9_RC00']\n20
> Jan 2021 04:04:50 INFO     Executing ['/usr/local/bin/ftl.par',
> '--name=asia.gcr.io/pyapp45-2020/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:2e34b5db-3bb2-4c20-9f35-86922c702148', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv',
> '--cache-repository=asia.gcr.io/pyapp45-2020/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d',
> '--no-cache', '--builder-output-path=""',
> '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig',
> '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7',
> '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip',
> '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG',
> '--base=asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20201213_3_7_9_RC00']\nINFO
> FTL version python-v0.17.0\nINFO     Beginning FTL build for
> python\nINFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_dir /env\nINFO     FTL arg
> passed: ttl 168\nINFO     FTL arg passed: python_cmd
> /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache
> False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_cmd virtualenv\nINFO
> FTL arg passed: entrypoint None\nINFO     FTL arg passed:
> exposed_ports None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: pip_cmd
> /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip\nINFO     FTL arg passed:
> tar_base_image_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: export_cache_stats
> False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: builder_output_path ""\nINFO     FTL
> arg passed: destination_path /srv\nINFO     FTL arg passed:
> sh_c_prefix False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: base
> asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20201213_3_7_9_RC00\nINFO
> FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.17.0\nINFO     FTL arg passed:
> cache_salt \nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_repository
> asia.gcr.io/pyapp45-2020/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d\nINFO
> FTL arg passed: venv_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv
> /env\nINFO     FTL arg passed: name
> asia.gcr.io/pyapp45-2020/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:2e34b5db-3bb2-4c20-9f35-86922c702148\nINFO
> FTL arg passed: global_cache False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: upload
> True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True\nINFO     FTL arg
> passed: output_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: directory
> /workspace\nINFO     FTL arg passed: additional_directory
> /.googleconfig\nINFO     FTL arg passed: verbosity DEBUG\nINFO
> starting: full build\nINFO     starting: builder initialization\nINFO
> Loading Docker credentials for repository
> 'asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20201213_3_7_9_RC00'\nINFO
> Loading Docker credentials for repository
> 'asia.gcr.io/pyapp45-2020/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:2e34b5db-3bb2-4c20-9f35-86922c702148'\nINFO
> builder initialization took 0 seconds\nINFO     starting: build
> process for FTL image\nINFO     starting:
> checking_cached_interpreter_layer\nINFO     starting: check py

Also, the log give me a full detailed logs, i'll paste the logs into pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/JtXCvr8s

Any help would be appreciated.

============================================================
EDIT:

I woke up the next day and the error was gone, not sure if it was something going on with google internals, but I spent 9 hours trying and retrying this build and everytime, same error, different step... If you are reading this and know what happened, feel free to comment below. Thanks.

Comment: it says `INVALID_ARGUMENT` but it's not clear what's invalid. You are saying that it fails randomly so I'm not sure what's heppening here. it could be a timeout or quota or anything else. I suggest that you [contact support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases) for such question for a full diagonize

Comment: okay, I just gave up on this error and went to sleep, in the next day I tried again and it worked perfecly, no change required at all. I think this was an google's internal error somehow, I literally didn't changed anything and it worked! My luck this project is in early stages, if this happened in a advanced stage I would be in a impossible situation...